# Summing across sub-sets from one row to another by a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm not very well versed in the syntax of SQL and am struggling to understand how to aggregate a simple set of data.

---

**The Problem:**

Based off of the `'Open'` and `'Closed'` timestamp, I must sum up the amount of time users spend in each workstation using the login history table below.

---

**Requirements:**

- Rows with empty workstation or username columns should be marked invalid
- Status' for each row ordered by timestamp that don't start with `'Open'` or end with `'Closed'` should also be marked as invalid
- Multiple `'Open'` status' before a `'Closed'` can still be considered valid, but the sum should start from the first occurrence of `'Open'`

---

```
+-----------------+-------------+--------+------------+-------------------------+
|       KEY       | WORKSTATION | STATUS |  USERNAME  |        TIMESTAMP        |
+-----------------+-------------+--------+------------+-------------------------+
| 181861-0001-001 |             | Closed |            | 2015-07-01 18:19:48.527 |
| 181861-0001-001 |             | Closed |            | 2015-07-01 20:20:46.383 |
| 181861-0001-001 | 1AHVW       | Open   | ANDJOH0427 | 2015-07-01 13:18:46.547 |
| 181861-0001-001 | 1AHVW       | Closed | ANDJOH0427 | 2015-07-01 14:11:41.920 |
| 181861-0001-001 | 1ALVW       | Closed | DWYGRE0609 | 2015-07-01 18:29:39.127 |
| 181861-0001-001 | 1ALVW       | Closed | DWYGRE0609 | 2015-07-01 18:29:40.300 |
| 181861-0001-001 | 1AHVW       | Closed | HORDOU0521 | 2015-07-01 19:27:34.667 |
| 181861-0001-001 | 1AHVW       | Closed | HORDOU0521 | 2015-07-01 19:44:36.167 |
| 181861-0001-001 | 1AQCI       | Open   | POUJON702  | 2015-07-02 00:46:37.540 |
| 181861-0001-001 | 1ALVW       | Open   | PRIADA747  | 2015-07-01 14:51:02.937 |
| 181861-0001-001 | 1ALVW       | Open   | PRIADA747  | 2015-07-01 15:29:48.357 |
| 181861-0001-001 | 1ALVW       | Open   | PRIADA747  | 2015-07-01 16:13:20.953 |
| 181861-0001-001 | 1ALVW       | Open   | PRIADA747  | 2015-07-01 17:49:42.717 |
| 181861-0001-001 | 1ALVW       | Closed | PRIADA747  | 2015-07-01 17:53:28.217 |
| 181861-0001-001 | 1ALVW       | Open   | PRIADA747  | 2015-07-01 18:34:11.043 |
| 181861-0001-001 | 1ALVW       | Closed | PRIADA747  | 2015-07-01 19:20:11.540 |
+-----------------+-------------+--------+------------+-------------------------+
```

**My (almost) Solution:**

```
SELECT Project, username, Workstation, 
min(case when [Status] = 'Open' then [TimeStamp] end) AS [Started],
max(case when [Status] = 'Closed' then [TimeStamp] end) as [Ended],
DATEDIFF(second, min(case when [Status] = 'Open' then [TimeStamp] end), max(case when [Status] = 'Closed' then [TimeStamp] end)) AS ActualSeconds
FROM History
GROUP BY Project, username, Workstation
```

Unfortunately, this query doesn't account for the cases when a user logins, logs out, then logs back into the same workstation.

Thus, I need to find the `MIN` of every set between an `'Open'` and `'Closed'` status.

**Expected Result:**

```
+-----------------+-------------+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------+
|       KEY       | WORKSTATION |  USERNAME  |        START TIME       |        END TIME         | SECONDS |
+-----------------+-------------+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------+
| 181861-0001-001 |             |            | NULL                    | 2015-07-01 18:19:48.527 | NULL    |
| 181861-0001-001 | 1AHVW       | ANDJOH0427 | 2015-07-01 13:18:46.547 | 2015-07-01 14:11:41.920 | 3175    |
| 181861-0001-001 | 1ALVW       | DWYGRE0609 | NULL                    | 2015-07-01 18:29:39.127 | NULL    |
| 181861-0001-001 | 1AHVW       | HORDOU0521 | NULL                    | 2015-07-01 19:27:34.667 | NULL    |
| 181861-0001-001 | 1AQCI       | POUJON702  | 2015-07-02 00:46:37.540 | NULL                    | NULL    |
| 181861-0001-001 | 1ALVW       | PRIADA747  | 2015-07-01 14:51:02.937 | 2015-07-01 17:53:28.217 | 10945   |
| 181861-0001-001 | 1ALVW       | PRIADA747  | 2015-07-01 18:34:11.043 | 2015-07-01 19:20:11.540 | 2760    |
+-----------------+-------------+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------+
```

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Show the result set that you want.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thank you! I am new to posting here :)

Comment: I don't understand your expected output. Why does `'POUJON702'` have two entries, and why does one of them have an `[END TIME]` of `'2015-07-01 19:20:11.540'`? They only have one entry, which is at `'2015-07-02 00:46:37.540'`. How are the other values generated? They don't appear relevant to the sample data we have.

Comment: Also, what happened to `'PRIADA747'`?

Comment: @Larnu Hey, I'm sorry! I made a mistake in the ending table.

Comment: What about `'POUJON702'` now? Why have they disappeared? `'PRIADA747'` never uses workstation `'1AQCI'`; why are they now related?

Comment: @Larnu G-dangit. The QCI entry is poujon702. I literally left my glasses at home today, so I'm struggling with legibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be close:

```
with data as (
    select *,
        row_number() over (partition by workstation order by timestamp) as tn,
        row_number() over (partition by workstation order by username, timestamp) as un,
        sum(case when status = 'Closed' then 1 end) over (
            partition by workstation, username order by timestamp desc) as sn
    from t
)
select workstation, username,
    min(case when status = 'Open' then timestamp end) as start_time,
    max(case when status = 'Closed' then timestamp end) as end_time,
    datediff(second,
        min(case when status = 'Open' then timestamp end),
        max(case when status = 'Closed' then timestamp end)) as diff,
    datediff(millisecond,
        min(case when status = 'Open' then timestamp end), 
        max(case when status = 'Closed' then timestamp end)) / 1000 as diff2,
case when count(*) > 1 then 'Valid' else 'Invalid' end as flag
from data
group by workstation, username, tn - un, sn;
```

http://rextester.com/JXS10553

I noticed that the time differences in your expected output didn't quite match up. The problem is because of the way `datediff()` counts time boundaries rather than measuring whole units (seconds in this case.) I've added a second way to compute the seconds that does produce what you were expecting.

Comment: Wow you were so close! PRIADA747 should return only three entries instead of four. I found a different solution and will post in a second.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually guess work, as the example data and the expected output the OP has provided don't appear to correlate. This provides the correct results for USERNAME's *`NULL`*, `'ANDJOH0427'`, `'HORDOU0521'`, and `'DWYGRE0609'`, however, returns a result for `'PRIADA747'` (which is excluded from the expected resultset) and gives a very different answer for `'POUJON702'`:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE #Sample ([KEY] varchar(15),
                      WORKSTATION varchar(5),
                      [STATUS] varchar(6),
                      USERNAME varchar(10),
                      [TIMESTAMP] datetime);

INSERT INTO #Sample
VALUES ('181861-0001-001',NULL,'Closed',NULL,'2015-07-01T18:19:48.527'),
       ('181861-0001-001',NULL,'Closed',NULL,'2015-07-01T20:20:46.383'),
       ('181861-0001-001','1AHVW','Open','ANDJOH0427','2015-07-01T13:18:46.547'),
       ('181861-0001-001','1AHVW','Closed','ANDJOH0427','2015-07-01T14:11:41.920'),
       ('181861-0001-001','1ALVW','Closed','DWYGRE0609','2015-07-01T18:29:39.127'),
       ('181861-0001-001','1ALVW','Closed','DWYGRE0609','2015-07-01T18:29:40.300'),
       ('181861-0001-001','1AHVW','Closed','HORDOU0521','2015-07-01T19:27:34.667'),
       ('181861-0001-001','1AHVW','Closed','HORDOU0521','2015-07-01T19:44:36.167'),
       ('181861-0001-001','1AQCI','Open','POUJON702','2015-07-02T00:46:37.540'),
       ('181861-0001-001','1ALVW','Open','PRIADA747','2015-07-01T14:51:02.937'),
       ('181861-0001-001','1ALVW','Open','PRIADA747','2015-07-01T15:29:48.357'),
       ('181861-0001-001','1ALVW','Open','PRIADA747','2015-07-01T16:13:20.953'),
       ('181861-0001-001','1ALVW','Open','PRIADA747','2015-07-01T17:49:42.717'),
       ('181861-0001-001','1ALVW','Closed','PRIADA747','2015-07-01T17:53:28.217'),
       ('181861-0001-001','1ALVW','Open','PRIADA747','2015-07-01T18:34:11.043'),
       ('181861-0001-001','1ALVW','Closed','PRIADA747','2015-07-01T19:20:11.540');
GO
SELECT *
FROM #Sample;
GO

WITH Starts AS(
    SELECT [KEY],
           WORKSTATION,
           USERNAME,
           [TIMESTAMP],
           NULLIF(MIN(ISNULL(CASE STATUS WHEN 'Open' THEN [TIMESTAMP] END,'20550101')) OVER (PARTITION BY [KEY], WORKSTATION, USERNAME),'20550101') AS StartTime
    FROM #Sample S)
SELECT [KEY],
       WORKSTATION,
       USERNAME,
       StartTime,
       MAX([TIMESTAMP]) AS EndTime,
       DATEDIFF(SECOND, StartTime, MAX([TIMESTAMP])) AS Seconds
FROM Starts
GROUP BY [KEY],
         WORKSTATION,
         USERNAME,
         StartTime;
GO      
DROP TABLE #Sample;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but unfortunately this does something quite similar to my original query. It is excluding the second start time for PRIADA747. I know that you posted this before I could update the expected result table.

Comment: @JohnMarkSill Yep, why it's important to make sure your sample and expected results are relevant to each other. :)